# How do I show two text views next to each other

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview, android-sdk-2.3

I have a Main Activity That has a Clickable Link that launches a Activity.  Right now what is showing is "Click Here" in a text view.  I would like to change it to : "To see Evacuation Routes - Click Here"  With the "Click Here" being the underlined text.  Below is the Code I currently have.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView_5"
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    AsyncRouteNames asyncRouteNames = new AsyncRouteNames();
    asyncRouteNames.execute();




    String mapStr = "Click Here";
    SpannableString mapContent = new SpannableString(mapStr);
    mapContent.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mapStr.length(), 0);
    final TextView mapTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    mapTxtView.setText(mapContent);
    mapTxtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    Linkify.addLinks(mapTxtView, Linkify.ALL);      
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isMobile = false;
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()){
        isMobile = true;
    }

    if (isMobile){
        mapTxtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EvacRouteTableActivity.class));
            }
        });
    } else {
        mapTxtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoConnectionActivity.class));
            }
        });         
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found what I needed with minimal change only to the activity_main.xml  and here it is.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1_1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:text="To view Evacuation Routes - "
        android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_1"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I added this code and it worked

Answer (score 10):

You can add a LinearLayout with orientation: "horizontal" and add both textviews in it.

```
<LinearLayout
         ...
         android:orientation="horizontal">
       <TextView .../>
       <TextView .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this should be the right answer 
very clean, you are a Pro :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display two object side by side use a`ndroid:layout_weight="2"` property.

Comment: <LinearLayout
         ...
         android:orientation="horizontal">
       <TextView ... android:layout_weight="2"/>
       <TextView ...android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>